# How to consume a JSON web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service exposed to me which returns a json object.

I've been provided with a url `http://address.to.web.service:8080/game`
If enter this in any browser i get a json output.

In my code, I've already implemented logic to populate a web page but using a local json file.

I now need to wire it up with the output of the web service.

Can someone help me understand what might be the simplest way to go for this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but, Is parsing a JSON using a url the same as getting JSON output from a webservice?

Comment: Define "webservice"... Invoking `http://address.to.web.service:8080/game` and processing its response sounds like "getting JSON output from a webservice". If you can enter that URL in your browser and see JSON then this is "parsing a JSON using a URL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to your webservice, read the full response and convert it to a JSON array. You do not specify which part of the problem you're having problems with.

Comment: Since doing this for first time, reading a lot and getting confused! I saw there is wsimport but not sure if that is the best option in this case?

Comment: tried wsimport, but since the webservice doesnt generate a wsdl... i'm not able to create the client code using wsimport.

Comment: don't know about wsimport  but this might help http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html